# PHP: Populated drop down menu and get posted item

Tags: php

I want to populate text file to drop down menu. Then, post the selected item to another text file.

The script does not work.  It only writes a blankline to "userinput.ini".

My code for index.php:

```
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<body>
</body>
</html>
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>

<?php
$clientcode = "clientcode.csv";
$read_clientcode = @fopen($clientcode, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $clientcode");
$clientcode_contents = fread($read_clientcode, filesize($clientcode));
$clientcode_array = explode("\n",$clientcode_contents);
fclose($read_clientcode);

echo '<select name="SITE">';
foreach($clientcode_array as $key => $value) {
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

My code for foo.php:

```
<?
$fp = "userinput.ini";
$fh = fopen($fp,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fh,$_POST['SITE']. "\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: The `<select>` is outside your `<form>` element.

Comment: Also, this opens up a slew of options for those who wish to hack your site. You're allowing any poster to write a file on your system. Think again.

Comment: Are you sure option value is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

you must have to end  end of file.
your code should be as follow

```
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<body>
</body>
</html>
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Confirm">
<?php
$clientcode = "clientcode.csv";
$read_clientcode = @fopen($clientcode, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $clientcode");
$clientcode_contents = fread($read_clientcode, filesize($clientcode));
$clientcode_array = explode("\n",$clientcode_contents);
fclose($read_clientcode);

echo '<select name="SITE">';
foreach($clientcode_array as $key => $value) {
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried your suggestion but it still writes a blankline to "userinput.ini".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP function fgetcsv()

Have that read the csv file to generate your pick list, then on foo.php have it also take that csv file again and this time use it as a white-list to check that the value has not been tampered with as Pål Brattberg has rightly commented.

Picking the csv file up twice might make you think about creating a shared function, or if this csv file only changes say, once a week, you might just bite the bullet and re-write the csv as a straightforward PHP array in a file - which you update when a new csv is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed:

index.php

```
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<body>
</body>
</html>
<form action="foo.php" method="post">

<?php
$clientcode = "clientcode.csv";
$read_clientcode = @fopen($clientcode, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $clientcode");
$clientcode_contents = fread($read_clientcode, filesize($clientcode));
$clientcode_array = explode("\n",$clientcode_contents);
fclose($read_clientcode);

echo '<select name="SITE">';
foreach($clientcode_array as $SITE) {
    echo ("<option");
    if ($HTTP_POST_VARS["SITE"] == $SITE) echo (" selected");
     echo (">$SITE");
  }
  ?></select><br>

<input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

foo.php

```
<?php
   echo $HTTP_POST_VARS['SITE'];
?>
```